# Laravel 5 asset function pointing to 127.0.01

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just completed my work on localhost and deployed my site on live. Site is working fine but my asset URL is pointing to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. So anybody have idea, why it's happening so?

I am using Laravel 5.

Comment: there may be caches exists while in development, try to remove it first especially `php artisan view:clear` for laravel >= 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not hardcoded a URL for the `url` property in `config/app.php` (default is `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`)

and

in your `.env` file, make sure your `APP_URL` is correct.

Then run `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @MahaDev, was the value in `APP_URL` incorrect?  If so, try testing your site in incognito.

Comment: There is no url like http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in whole project. where from it is coming?

Comment: Check the `url` property of `config/app.php`.  Confirm that it is set to: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`

Comment: I don't understand your response.

Comment: My site name doesn't contain the localhost or 127.0.0.1. So i set my 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://mysitename')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135382/discussion-between-raphael-rafatpanah-and-maha-dev).

Answer (score 1):

set `APP_URL=http://yourdoamin` in .ENV file and try running your app with `php artisan serve`

Comment: No need to remove it.  However, OP should know that these are the same.  However, it is better to us `.env` files for this so you can manage different environments with one code base.  In fact, OP should make sure that he did not hard code some value here.  Update your answer to make sure that he did not.